# Why On board Intel and Dedicated Graphic cards are both enabled

Tags: graphics-card

I recently bought an Acer laptop which has On board Intel and Dedicated Graphic card(Nvidia) both enabled.

Is this normal?

As a test I disabled Intel graphic card and then did a Novabench performance test.
The score reduced by 50%. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite normal.

Your laptop has the [NVIDIA Optimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus) architecture,
supposedly being able to automatically switch between two graphics adapters
to provide either maximum performance or minimum power draw to optimize
battery life.
To this end, this laptop has both the on-board Intel card and an NVIDIA.

The Intel is supposed to handle simple screen draws, like displaying the
desktop, using minimum power and conserving battery life.

The NVIDIA will kick-in for more demanding tasks, such as video display.